# What is the .springBeans file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a small Spring project recently and this file appeared in project root folder:

**.springBeans**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beansProjectDescription>
    <version>1</version>
    <pluginVersion><![CDATA[3.6.3.201411271034-RELEASE]]></pluginVersion>
    <configSuffixes>
        <configSuffix><![CDATA[xml]]></configSuffix>
    </configSuffixes>
    <enableImports><![CDATA[false]]></enableImports>
    <configs>
        <config>src/test/resources/eu/gondy/myproject/test-beans.xml</config>
    </configs>
    <autoconfigs>
        <config>java:eu.gondy.myproject.rest.RestApiController</config>
    </autoconfigs>
    <configSets>
    </configSets>
</beansProjectDescription>
```

What is this file and it's purpose?

Technologies I use in this project: Spring 4.1.4, Spring Boot 1.2.1, Gradle 2.3, Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you open `Spring Explorer` tab in Eclipse (you have to select your project afterwards) there you should see `Config Files` tab.

Here you can add your configuration files for example, and everything added in this list which you see will be stored in `.springBeans` file, which is single configuration point for Spring.

Comment: So this file is important to Spring? Or can I safely remove it?

Comment: This file is required if you are using Eclipse IDE. If you delete it, I believe it will be created again. This is really IDE specific file which is needed to handle spring configurations. Note, that you can modify it manually too (useful comments here https://jira.spring.io/browse/IDE-335)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the idea. what's its purpose ? Is it parsed when we start a spring application ? I'm using intellij. Can i just remove this file ?

Comment: So Is this a file that should be left out of SVN/GIT?

Comment: @GeorgePhillips Yes, it should be ignored. To make sure, you can see it ignored in spring-boot project for example - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/.gitignore